# Probability Theory - Independence of Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

I am given that $Y\:\&\:Z$ are discrete random variables and $W\:\&\:X$ are continuous random variables with $Y,Z\in\left\{0,1\right\}$.

I am given that $$P\left( W=w \: \vert \: X=x,Y=y,Z=z\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac{(w-z)^2}{2} \right)$$ and $$P\left( X=x \: \vert \: Y=y,Z=z \right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{2} \right).$$

Is it enough to say that $X\:\&\:Z$ are independent as the second equation does not depend on $z$? Similarly, is it enough to say that $W\:\&\:Z$ are not independent as the first equation does depend on both $w$ and $z$?

Comment: The hypothesis is absurd and should be replaced by the fact that, for every Borel set $B$, $$P\left( W\in B \mid X=x,Y=y,Z=z\right)=\int_B\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac{(w-z)^2}{2} \right)dw$$ and $$P\left( X\in B \mid Y=y,Z=z \right)=\int_B\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{2} \right)dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have: $\mathsf P(U\leq u\mid T=t, V=v) \;=\; g(t,u)$ where $U, V$ are continuous random variables, and $T$ is discrete, and $v$ is not free in $g(t,u)$.   Then we do have that:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(U\leq u\mid T=t) & = \int\limits_{V(\Omega)} \mathsf P(U\leq u\mid T=t, V=v) f_V(v)\operatorname d v 
\\[1ex] & = \int\limits_{V(\Omega)} g(t,u)\;f_V(v)\operatorname d v
\\[1ex] & = g(t,u)\cdot\int\limits_{V(\Omega)} f_V(v)\operatorname d v
\\[1ex] & = \mathsf P(U\leq u\mid T=t, V=v)
\end{align}$$

**tl;dr** Yes, you can say that $U$ and $V$ are *conditionally independent* given $T$.

Comment: That's a great explanation for *conditional independence*, but the question asked me to show that they are *independent*

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.

Remember two events A and B are independent if and only if their joint probability equals the product of their probabilities: $\mathrm{P}(A \cap B) = \mathrm{P}(A)\mathrm{P}(B)$.

Comment: Or if $P(A\mid B) = P(A)$

Comment: I know that, but from the equations I am given I cannot see how I can manipulate them in order to get what you have stated.